# cmd error:could not find or load main class while executing core java in maven

Tags: java, maven-3

I'm getting an error:

```
Could not find or load main class com.javatpoint.
```

App while executing a simple core java application of maven in command prompt given in javatpoint maven tutorial.

I'm able to compile the project but not able to run the project.
The link of the example
http://www.javatpoint.com/maven-example

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
Add classpath before running your example. In the webpage is already written:

```
java -classpath target\CubeGenerator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;.; com.javatpoint.App
```

or

Add main class in maven-jar-plugin
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-specify-a-main-class-in-the-manifest-of-my-generated-jar-file.html
And then just run it:

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar
```